# doctype messes whole document how to fix?

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, doctype

ok so i foolishly didnt add doctype from the start, and i need to add one because i want to use a jquery script and it meeses up in IE9 for some reason (argh dam you). so i need to add a doctype

however it messes up my button spacing and such and have no idea how to fix, ill link to both documents

without doctype
http://viewpictures-loginlive.freehostia.com/Website%202/chandeliersale1.html

with doctype
http://viewpictures-loginlive.freehostia.com/Website%202/chandeliersale12.html

1) is there anyway to make the jquery image script work in ie9 without adding doctype? because firefox and chrome it displays perfectly..

2) how can i make the button spacing correct or can anyone help on the doctype document?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't add the !DOCTYPE from the beginning, the browsers rendered the code in Quirks mode. This mode exists only for compatibility with old websites (which don't have !DOCTYPE declarations), and may vary between browsers. Strict or W3C Standards mode relies on the !DOCTYPE declaration, and is rendered equally in all browsers.

Quirks and Standards modes render completely differently. That's why the whole site style looks broken in Standards mode (at least, it looks broken for me on Chrome). There is no easy fix for this, I'm afraid: you'll need to rewrite the style for your website in Standards mode. From now on, you should always add the !DOCTYPE declaration from the beginning.